# C# How to separate the control and the custom designer for the control

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

Is it possible to separate the custom control implementation from the custom control designer implementation? As example:

> MyAsembly.dll
>
> MyAssembly.Design.dll

I mean with custom designer a class that inherits from the `ControlDesigner` class (see: [MSDN ControlDesigner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner.aspx)) (Not the designer generated code).

Answer (score 0):

The custom designer (`ControlDesigner`) is a class separate from the control itself. It is attached to the control via the  `DesignerAttribute`. Just create a new class library project in your solution and place the designer there. In .NET, each project creates its own dll or exe file.

Comment: I'm curious, since I've never looked into this at all - are you able to design that control if the DLL for the controller isn't there?

Comment: @Bobson: You can specify the designer by name or by type in the `DesignerAttribute`. If you specify it by name the dll will not be required in the runnning program; however, in design mode the control will be added like component (on the lower band) instead as control (tested).